# string was not recognized as valid BOOL

Tags: c#, string, parsing, boolean

```
 oComm = CreateCommand("IsMapAccessExist", spParams, TypeOfConnectionString.GeoAppBuilder);

bool exists = true;    
    exists = Boolean.Parse(oComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    return exist
```

exists has the value 'true' but it throws the error

```
FormatException was caught
String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

Comment: Are you sure? `Boolean.Parse("true")` works fine. Your string has these single quotes also? Did you debug your code and check what `ExecuteScalar` returns exactly?

Comment: its being set as true, beforehand but yea, the Boolean.Parse(oComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) flags that error....and i checked in the database with SQL the record exists

Comment: What is returned in `oComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString()`? It throws exception when it tries to convert what is returned in `oComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` to Boolean.

Comment: your problem lies with oComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), it is not returning 'true'or 'false' and hence the FormatException is thrown.

Comment: 730...not sure why though as IsMapAccessExist, is a stored procedure which returns the record

Comment: `.ExecuteScalar()` does not return a `Boolean` value.

Comment: .ExecuteScalar() need not return a Boolean value as long as its ToString() returns either "True" or "False", e.g. `public class Example { public override ToString() { return "True"; } }`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like `ExecuteScalar` returned something that *wasn't* `"True"` or `"False"`; perhaps `"1"` or `"0"`. Here's how you debug it:

```
var tmp = oComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
exists = Boolean.Parse(tmp);
```

Then *look at what `tmp` holds* in a debugger.

Comment: Also log the offending value if this happens in production

Answer (score 1):

`.ExecuteScalar()` returns the first column of the first row. To make it work, do something like this:

```
int col = (int)oComm.ExecuteScalar();
if(col == null)
    exists = false;
else
    exists = true;
```

Comment: If col != null it can still contain a value evaluating to `false`.

Comment: That assumes that you intend working to mean: false === no rows selected, true === at least one row selected; this might or might not be what is intended

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar not returning boolean. Read documentation [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: en-* documentation is preferable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx ; as for what type it returns: it could be *pretty much* anything, *boxed* as an `object`

Answer (score 0):

[`Boolean.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) **MUST** be passed either "True" ([`Boolean.TrueString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.truestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) or "False" ([`Boolean.FalseString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.falsestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

You might be better off using [`Boolean.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead, e.g.:

```
string value = "true";
bool couldParseString = Boolean.TryParse(value, out value);
if ( couldParseString )
{
    // do some stuff
}
else
{
    // handle the string not being correct
}
```

Note: you should generally aim to use {type}.**Try**Parse instead of Parse.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's late , here is an answer using `Boolean.TryParse`.

```
bool exists;    // No need to assign   
Boolean.TryParse(oComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString(),exists); // using TryParse

return exist;
```

Explanation : ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

> If the conversion `succeeded`, contains `true` if value is equal to
>   `TrueString` or `false` if value is equal to `FalseString`. If the
>   conversion `failed`, contains `false`.

You will always get a desired value even if the value is not a valid `TrueString` or `FalseString` field.

Intention is to avoid exceptions at any cost. Even failure will return a `false` but program will continue without a stop.

> The TryParse method is like the Parse method, except the TryParse method does not throw an exception if the conversion fails.